# glmnet plots - no axes or labels

Tags: r, glmnet

I'm playing around with the standard plots in glmnet and am having an issue - axes and labels aren't being displayed.

If I try:

```
cv <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial", type.measure = "class")
plot(cv)

mod <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, family = "binomial")
plot(mod)
```

I get:

[image: cv]

and

[image: mod]

Any ideas?

I'm using R 3.5.0.and glmnet v.2.0-16.

Comment: It works fine for me with `R 3.3.2` and `glmnet 2.0-16`

Comment: How weird - it works fine on my other computer, but not this one. I wonder why.

Comment: Did you try `dev.off()`?

Comment: That solved it - thanks.

Comment: Perfect @LucaS. I will therefore put my comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run `dev.off()` before the `plot()` command.